# Where is the best place for demon hunting? (kill 100,000 demons achievement)

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

The Hunter or Hunted achievement requires you to kill 100,000 demons. Where is the best place for demon hunting?

It is not about experience/time efficiency; it is just about getting the highest possible count of **demon kills** in a single run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Act 4, Quest 1.

When you fight Iskatu, there will be lots of these tiny black demons. Just take some *Thorns* equipment and start the game there on *Normal*. Let them hit you, kill em with thorns, restart.

Each time there are approximately 350 of these demons

Answer (score 3):

Most of Act IV consists of Demon classified creatures.  The suggestion to farm Act IV Quest I is appropriate, however you should probably use Blackthorn's set to gain immunity from Molten or have sufficient health regeneration to accommodate it being layered on you while you stand still (if simply afk farming the demons).

I propose however that you run all of Act IV or run Act IV bounties to complete this achievement since you will also gain the Act IV caches which may contain a ring of royal grandeur (which is why people farm Act I caches).

You're certain to gain a number of levels, gems, etc with this method as opposed to the mindless farming which requires nearly 300 game resets (based on 350 small demons).

If you can pull this off in Torment 1 efficiently you should also be able to simultaneously farm a number of keys towards your Hellfire crafting requirements.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion: Act III from The Breached Keep to Siegebreaker inclusive.
Or only The Breached Keep.

More variants [on Battle.net forums](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/8796351234) with kill/min statistics.

Comment: The link is for exp/hour routes, leveling routes, the question is about slaying demons only.

Comment: @givanse the link is for kill/min too, take a closer look

Comment: Those are impressive and pretty useful stats. Still no demon specific runs.

Answer (score 0):

war that time forgot. its in the battlefields of eternity. kill the angel and stand in the starting point by the "time lock" and let the demon captain summon his unlimited timelost demonic marauders. make sure your xbox autoshut off is not on.